# How do I remove duplicate records in a join table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, duplication

I have a table that has a schema like this:

```
create_table "questions_tags", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
        t.integer "question_id"
        t.integer "tag_id"
      end

      add_index "questions_tags", ["question_id"], :name => "index_questions_tags_on_question_id"
      add_index "questions_tags", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_questions_tags_on_tag_id"
```

I would like to remove records that are duplicates, i.e. they have both the same `tag_id` and `question_id` as another record.

What does the SQL look like for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my experience (and as shown in many tests) `NOT IN` as [demonstrated by @gsiems](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36542/3684) is rather slow and scales terribly. The inverse `IN` is typically faster (where you can reformulate that way, like in this case), but this query with [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) (doing exactly what you asked) should be much faster yet - with big tables **by orders of magnitude**:

```
DELETE FROM questions_tags q
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM questions_tags q1
   WHERE  q1.ctid < q.ctid
   AND    q1.question_id = q.question_id
   AND    q1.tag_id = q.tag_id
   );
```

Deletes every row where *another row with the same `(tag_id, question_id)` and a smaller `ctid` exists*. (Effectively keeps the first instance according to the physical order of tuples.) Using `ctid` in the absence of a better alternative, your table does not seem to have a PK or any other unique (set of) column(s).

`ctid` is the internal tuple identifier present in *every* row and necessarily unique. Further reading:

- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers/66007#66007)
- [How list all tables with data changes in the last 24 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512888/939860)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

### Test

I ran a test case with this table matched to your question and 100k rows:

```
CREATE TABLE questions_tags(
  question_id integer NOT NULL
, tag_id      integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO questions_tags (question_id, tag_id)
SELECT (random()* 100)::int, (random()* 100)::int
FROM   generate_series(1, 100000);

ANALYZE questions_tags;
```

Indexes do not help in this case.

#### Results

**`NOT IN`**
The [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ce47b8/3) times out.
Tried the same locally but I canceled it, too, after several minutes.

**`EXISTS`**
Finishes in half a second in this [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ce47b8/2).

#### Alternatives

**If** you are going to delete *most of the rows*, it will be faster to select the survivors into another table, drop the original and rename the survivor's table. Careful, this has implications if you have view or foreign keys (or other dependencies) defined on the original.

If you have dependencies and want to keep them, you could:

- Drop all foreign keys and indexes - for performance.
- `SELECT` survivors to a temporary table.
- `TRUNCATE` the original.
- Re-`INSERT` survivors.
- Re-`CREATE` indexes and foreign keys.
  Views can just stay, they have no impact on performance. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290900/pg-best-way-to-delete-millions-of-rows-by-id/8290958#8290958) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries-in-postgresql/8826879#8826879).

Comment: ++ for the exists solution. Much better than my suggestion.

Comment: Could you please explain the ctid comparison in your WHERE clause?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: I added some explanation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ctid to accomplish that. For example:

Create a table with duplicates:

```
=# create table foo (id1 integer, id2 integer);
CREATE TABLE

=# insert into foo values (1,1), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3);
INSERT 0 4

=# select * from foo;
 id1 | id2 
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   1 |   2
   1 |   2
   1 |   3
(4 rows)
```

Select the duplicate data:

```
=# select foo.ctid, foo.id1, foo.id2, foo2.min_ctid
-#  from foo
-#  join (
-#      select id1, id2, min(ctid) as min_ctid 
-#          from foo 
-#          group by id1, id2 
-#          having count (*) > 1
-#      ) foo2 
-#      on foo.id1 = foo2.id1 and foo.id2 = foo2.id2
-#  where foo.ctid <> foo2.min_ctid ;
 ctid  | id1 | id2 | min_ctid 
-------+-----+-----+----------
 (0,3) |   1 |   2 | (0,2)
(1 row)
```

Delete the duplicate data:

```
=# delete from foo
-# where ctid not in (select min (ctid) as min_ctid from foo group by id1, id2);
DELETE 1

=# select * from foo;
 id1 | id2 
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   1 |   2
   1 |   3
(3 rows)
```

In your case the following should work:

```
delete from questions_tags
    where ctid not in (
        select min (ctid) as min_ctid 
            from questions_tags 
            group by question_id, tag_id
        );
```

Comment: Where can I read more about this `ctid`? Thanks.

Comment: @marcamillion -- The documentation has a short blurb on ctids at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: What does `ctid` stand for?

Comment: @marcamillion -- tid == "tuple id", not sure what the c means.