# How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, datatypes, cast, data-pages

Each row in a table has a [system column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html) `ctid` of type `tid` that represents the physical location of the row:

> ```
> create table t(id serial);
> insert into t default values;
> insert into t default values;
> ```

> ```
> select ctid
>      , id
> from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> ctid  | id
> :---- | -:
> (0,1) |  1
> (0,2) |  2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=98abf5bffd03364076bd4cd4b30feb6e)*

What's the best way of getting just the page number as from the `ctid` in the most appropriate type (eg `integer`, `bigint` or `numeric(1000,0)`)?

The [only way I can think of](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=1dc8740cf72ca8a8c7c1a26113e6d442) is very ugly.

Comment: IIRC it is a vector type and we don't have accessor methods on these.  I am not sure if you can do it from a C function.  Craig will tell for sure :)

Comment: Can you cast as POINT? Eg. `select ct[0], ct[1] from (select ctid::text::point as ct from pg_class where ...) y;`

Comment: The title suggests you are after both the *page number* and the *tuple index*, later you narrow down to page number. I went with the version in the body, tuple index is a trivial extension.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
SELECT (ctid::text::point)[0]::bigint AS block_number FROM t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9a7f6b457699a63bef2316422c3350d1)*

@bma suggested something similar in [his comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers#comment118665_65964). Here is a ...

#### Rationale for the type

`ctid` is of type `tid` (tuple identifier), called `ItemPointer` in the C-language source code. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)

> This is the data type of the system column `ctid`. A tuple ID is a
> pair (**block number**, **tuple index within block**) that identifies the
> physical location of the row within its table.

Bold emphasis mine. [And:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

> (`ItemPointer`, also known as `CTID`)

A block is **8 KB** in standard installations. [Maximum Table Size is **32 TB**.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html) It follows logically that block numbers must accommodate *at least* a maximum of (fixed per @Daniel's comment):

```
SELECT (2^45 / 2^13)::int      -- = 2^32 = 4294967294
```

Which would fit into an unsigned `integer`. On further investigation I found [**in the source code**](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/storage/block.h) that ...

> blocks are numbered sequentially, **0 to 0xFFFFFFFE**.

Bold emphasis mine. Which confirms the first calculation:

```
SELECT 'xFFFFFFFE'::bit(32)::int8 -- max page number: 4294967294
```

Postgres uses signed integer and is therefore one bit short. I couldn't pin down, yet, whether the text representation is shifted to accommodate signed integer. Until somebody can clear this up, I would fall back to **`bigint`**, which works in any case.

#### Cast

There is [no registered cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html) for the `tid` type in Postgres 9.3 (still true in Postgres 13):

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_cast
WHERE  castsource = 'tid'::regtype
OR     casttarget = 'tid'::regtype;

 castsource | casttarget | castfunc | castcontext | castmethod
------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

You can still cast to `text`. There is a [text representation for every type in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html):

> Another important exception is that "automatic I/O conversion casts",
> those performed using a data type's own I/O functions to convert to or
> from text or other string types, are not explicitly represented in
> `pg_cast`.

The text representation matches that of a point, which consists of two `float8` numbers, that cast is lossless.

You can access the first number of a point with index 0. Cast to `bigint`. Voilá.

### Performance

I ran a quick test in Postgres 9.4 on a table with 30k rows (best of 5) with a couple of expressions that came to mind, including your original:

```
SELECT (ctid::text::point)[0]::int                              --  25 ms
     , right(split_part(ctid::text, ',', 1), -1)::int           --  28 ms
     , ltrim(split_part(ctid::text, ',', 1), '(')::int          --  29 ms
     , (ctid::text::t_tid).page_number                          --  31 ms
     , (translate(ctid::text,'()', '{}')::int[])[1]             --  45 ms
     , (replace(replace(ctid::text,'(','{'),')','}')::int[])[1] --  51 ms
     , substring(right(ctid::text, -1), '^\d+')::int            --  52 ms
     , substring(ctid::text, '^\((\d+),')::int                  -- 143 ms
FROM   tbl;
```

`int` instead of `bigint`, mostly irrelevant for the purpose of the test. I eventually repeated the test in Postgres 13 with `bigint` on a table with 50k rows. Results are largely the same!

The cast to `t_tid` builds on a user-defined composite type, like @Jake commented.
The gist of it: Casting tends to be faster than string manipulation. Regular expressions are expensive. The above solution is shortest and fastest.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, useful stuff. From [here](http://facility9.com/2011/04/postgresql-update-internals/) it looks like `ctid` is 6 bytes with 4 for the page and 2 for the row. I was worried about casting to `float` but I guess I needn't have from what you say here. It looks like [a user defined composite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/84a9b/2) type is much slower then using `point`, do you find that too?

Comment: @JackDouglas: Upon further investigation I have fallen back to `bigint`. Consider the update.

Comment: @JackDouglas: I like your idea of a cast to a composite type. It's clean and performs very well - even if the cast to `point` and back to `int8` is still faster). Cast to predefined types will always be a bit faster. I added it to my test to compare. I'd make that `(page_number bigint, row_number integer)` to be sure.

Comment: `2^40` is only 1TB, not 32TB which is `2^45`, which divided by `2^13` gives `2^32`, hence the full 32 bits being necessary for the page number.

Comment: @DanielVérité: Good catch, thanx. I amended accordingly. That removes the phantom mismatch.

Comment: Also perhaps worthy of note is that [pg_freespacemap](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgfreespacemap.html) uses `bigint` for blkno

Comment: up.  This helped me delete a duplicate row: `delete from contact where ((ctid::text::point)[1]::bigint = 1);`

Comment: @radarbob: For the record: to identify duplicates, you can operate with the `ctid` directly. Like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36614/3684