# Why insert in with is returning unexpected results?

Tags: postgresql, cte, dml

## Context

#### Schema setup

```
create table users( id serial primary key );
```

#### Query 1

```
with t1 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
), t2 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
)
select id from t1;
```

Expectations

```
1
```

Result

```
1
```

#### Query 2

```
with t1 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
), t2 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
)
select id from t2;
```

Expectations

```
2
```

Result

```
1
```

#### Query 3

```
with t1 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
), t2 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
)
select id from t1
union all
select id from t2;
```

Expectations (taking in account results of Query 2)

```
1
1
```

Result

```
1
2
```

## Question

What's wrong with my expectations and how to get the expected value from Query 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected and documented behaviour

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable

In your second query the database apparently chose to run `t2` before `t1` and thus it returns `1`.

In the third query there **have** to be two different values, because that's what a sequence guarantees: it never generates the same number twice (unless you have enabled `cycle`)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So there is no other way to get the latest inserted Id with that query than `select max( id ) from ( select Id from t1 union all ... from tN )`?

Comment: @bessgeor If you need to distinguish between the id inserted in the first statement and the one inserted in the second you need to use two separate statements, not a data modifying CTE (and then you can easily use `lastval()`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think you can also chain the CTEs, so the order of their execution is predictable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there any doc on _how_ database is choosing when to run one statement or another in CTE or is it an implementation detail on which one should not relate?

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ what do you mean under CTE chaining?

Comment: @bessgeor it's a detail. The link provided in the answer is what you need to know. But what I don't understand, is why do you need two CTEs to be inserting into the same table? You know you can insert 2 (or more) rows in a single CTE, right?

Comment: "Chaining": use `t1` inside `t2`. Something like: `with t1 as (
    insert into users default values
    returning id
), t2 as (
    insert into users (select nextval('users_id_seq') where exists (table t1))
    returning id
) select id from t2;`

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ yes, I know it but don't want to rely on [unguaranteed order](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95822/does-postgres-preserve-insertion-order-of-records). BTW it will make it impossible to do related entities insert (oversimplified example: add two users and one login for each, where login "John" should be bound to user 1 and login "Doe" to user 2 because some of the user data is specific to a particular login).

To add some context, I am writing simple CR-only sql generator, so I have to use pretty generic statements not to overcomplicate query generation.

Comment: @bessgeor: the simple solution is: don't use a CTE. Use single INSERT statements in the correct order in a single transaction.