# Pre-sorting postgres table instead of running CLUSTER

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Does pre-sorting a csv by a designated column and then inserting the data into postgres have the same effect as not pre-sorting, importing the data, creating the index and then CLUSTERing the table using that index?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the index you mentioned, and it being the default `CLUSTER` sort order now (Postgres remembers), both tables will turn out identical. Same order, no bloat.

Parallelism could potentially change this. But for now, writing queries are not parallelized. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html)

> Even when it is in general possible for parallel query plans to be
>   generated, the planner will not generate them for a given query if any
>   of the following are true:
>
> - The query **writes any data** or locks any database rows. If a query contains a data-modifying operation either at the top level or within
>     a CTE, no parallel plans for that query will be generated. As an
>     exception, the commands `CREATE TABLE ... AS`, `SELECT INTO`, and `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW`
>     which create a new table and populate it can use a parallel plan.

So neither `INSERT` nor `COPY` use parallel queries and a single process writes rows as received, i.e. in the order of the CSV file - even if there are no formal guarantees. Tables are *heaps* in theory and Postgres (like most RDBMS) generally treats the physical order of rows as implementation detail. But in the current implementation order is preserved, and that won't change without good reason. Parallelism would be a good reason, but that's hard to implement for writing queries.

Related:

- [Does (or can) the PostgreSQL `COPY TO` command guarantee a particular row order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622947/939860)
- [Does Postgres preserve insertion order of records?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95822/does-postgres-preserve-insertion-order-of-records/95852#95852)

Comment: What do you mean with "aside from the index you mentioned"  in the first sentence?

Comment: I mean the index he mentioned. It's there (and needed) in the 2nd scenario, but not in the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is empty before you begin, the result will be the same.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this true for a partitioned table?

Comment: If you could `CLUSTER` a partitioned table, it would also be true. As it is, you get `ERROR:  cannot cluster a partitioned table`. As it is, you have to cluster the partitions (which makes much more sense anyway).

Comment: A couple more caveats.  His system sort utility needs to understand the .csv files the same way his loader does, and it must be using the same locale/collation.