# What is the data type of the ‘ctid’ system column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgresql-10, uniqueidentifier

The Postgres system columns are documented in [*Chapter 5. Data Definition > 5.4. System Columns*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html).

That page mentions that `oid` values “are 32-bit quantities”. And that page says the same about transaction identifiers. So I will assume that means `oid`, `tableoid`, `xmin`, `cmin`, `xmax`, and `cmax` are all 32-bit integers.

But that leaves the `ctid` system column.

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

➡ What is the data type of the `ctid` column?

Specifically I am interested in version Postgres 10.3, but if it has changed over past versions, that would be good to know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## `tid`

See the manual page, [*Chapter 8. Data Types > 8.18. Object Identifier Types*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html). It explains that the data type is Postgres-specific, and known as `tid`.

> A final identifier type used by the system is tid, or tuple identifier (row identifier). This is the data type of the system column ctid. A tuple ID is a pair (block number, tuple index within block) that identifies the physical location of the row within its table.

You might find this similar Question interesting: [*How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/65964/19079)

By the way, if you are interested in this topic of `ctid` & `tid`, you might likely be interested in two new features of Postgres 12: (a) [OIDs demoted to normal columns](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/04/24/oid-column.html), and (b) the pluggable table storage / Access Methods feature new in Postgres 12 and later. See [Robert Haas Blog](http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2018/01/do-or-undo-there-is-no-vacuum.html), [Michael Paquier post](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-12-table-am-blackhole/), [zheap announcement in pg hackers mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAA4eK1+YtM5vxzSM2NZm+pC37MCwyvtkmJrO_yRBQeZDp9Wa2w@mail.gmail.com), [Zheap PG Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Zheap), and [Andres Anarazel youtube video in pgcon'19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTfvA9EQIz8&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: I have an additional question regarding the `tid` type? It it comparable? For instance, can you use `min(ctid)` in a query?

Comment: @DirtyHenry Why would you want to compare or rank the physical storage location of a tuple? If you have a serious use-case in mind, I suggest posting a Question here s Stack Exchange.

Comment: @BasilBourque Actually he's right; if you google delete duplicate rows in postgres without unique id, you find people resort to `ctid` as almost the only way plausible.

Answer (score 2):

CTID is another name for `ItemPointer`. It's basically a pointer to the tuples stored on the page. See `bufpage.h` header comment in PostgreSQL source code.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/storage-page-layout.html