# Is the system column "ctid" legitimate for identifying rows to delete?

Tags: postgresql, performance, delete, concurrency, postgresql-performance

I have a table with hundreds of millions of rows that I need to delete data from.

The existing indexes are the most efficient.

I can however use the existing indexes to find the rows to delete by using the `ctid` values:

```
DELETE FROM calendar_event WHERE ctid IN
(SELECT ctid FROM calendar_event WHERE user_id = 5 LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE)
```

What are the risks of relying on the `ctid` in this case? My worst case scenario is deleting the wrong the row.

Answer (score 14):

The `ROW SHARE` lock taken by `FOR UPDATE` prevents concurrent write access that would change the physical location of the row. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS)

> This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other
> transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other
> transactions that attempt `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, `SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE`, `SELECT FOR SHARE` or `SELECT FOR KEY SHARE` of these
> rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends;

So the `ctid` should be stable for the duration of the command (or the transaction, even) unless you alter the row within the same transaction yourself. `ctid` is still a system column for internal use and the project will not offer any guarantees. If you have *any* unique (combination of) column(s) (including the PK) use that instead of the `ctid`.

**However**, I would use a CTE to materialize the selection and avoid unexpected results.

And without `ORDER BY` you select arbitrary rows for deletion. You might as well add `SKIP LOCKED` to minimize lock contention with concurrent transactions:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ctid
   FROM   calendar_event
   WHERE  user_id = 5
   LIMIT  100
   FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
   )
DELETE FROM calendar_event WHERE ctid IN (TABLE cte);
```

Related, with **explanation** for both considerations:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

About `ctid`:

- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers/66007#66007)

Answer (score 3):

There actually *is* a serious pitfall with using ctid for identifying rows to delete: *in partitioned tables, ctid is not unique*. It is only unique in a given partition so, if one uses it as a criterion for deletion, this will likely result in deleting the desired row as well as the otherwise totally unrelated rows from other partitions (ask me how I know :-/ ).

What is actually unique in partitioned tables is {tableoid, ctid}, so the proper way to do it would be something like:

```
delete from my_table
where (tableoid, ctid) in 
(
    select tableoid, ctid 
    from my_table 
    where <deletion_predicate>
)
```

(For convenience, you can substitute `tableoid` with `tableoid::pg_catalog.regclass` - this is the actual partition name.)

This will work for non-partitioned tables too, as `tableoid` will be the same for all rows.