# Mismatch between the total number of rows in a sql join

Tags: postgresql, join

When I join entries from the points table (n = 34, 436) to the mid_pts table (n=1.98 million) the total number of rows of the table_joined is n = 26,016.  However, when I add the unjoined_pts table of n = 9,627 to the table_joined it doesn't match the original 'point' table number, it exceeds it by 1207.

The following are examples of the tables I have:

points table:

| LIC_LI_NO | DESCRIPTOR | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11112-01 | 04-81-09-01 | xx | xyz | xx |
| 11112-01 | 04-81-09-01 | xyz | x | x |
| 11119-03 | 04-81-09-01 | xx | xx | xyz |
| 11117-05 | 04-81-09-01 | xx | xyz | xyz |

mid_pts table

| LIC_LI_NO | ORIG_LICLI | DESCRIPTOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11112-01 | 11112-01 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 11112-01 | 11112-01 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 11119-03 | 11119-03 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 129517-05 | 11117-05 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 10000-01 | 10000-01 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 100232-01 | 100232-01 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 19-03 | 19-03 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 117-05 | 117-05 | 04-81-09-01 |
| 112-01 | 112-01 | 04-81-09-01 |

The table below is what I am expecting, but for some reason, as suggested by Laurenz Albe, a single row in my points table can relate to several rows in the mid_pts table.  I would like each row in the points table to join to just one candidate row in the mid_pts table.

table_joined

| LIC_LI_NO | ORIG_LICLI | DESCRIPTOR | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11112-01 | 11112-01 | 04-81-09-01 | xx | xyz | xx |
| 11112-01 | 11112-01 | 04-81-09-01 | xyz | x | x |
| 11119-03 | 11119-03 | 04-81-09-01 | xx | xx | xyz |
| 129517-05 | 11117-05 | 04-81-09-01 | xx | xyz | xyz |

```
CREATE TABLE table_joined AS
        SELECT m.geom, m.lic_li_no, m.orig_licli, p.id, p.descriptor, ... 
        FROM mid_pts m
        JOIN point p            
            ON CASE                                                     
            WHEN p.lic_li_no = m.lic_li_no THEN 1
            WHEN p.lic_li_no = m.orig_licli THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END = 1
            AND 
            (p.descriptor = m.descriptor)
    ;
```

When evaluated how many points didn't joined I get 9,627.

```
CREATE TABLE unjoined_pts AS 
        SELECT
        p.*
        FROM point p                                                  
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  table_joined m 
                          WHERE m.id = p.id)                    
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like each row in the `points` table to join to just one candidate row in the `mid_pts` table.

Simple solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.ctid)
       m.geom, m.lic_li_no, m.orig_licli, p.id, p.descriptor, ... 
FROM   point p
JOIN   mid_pts m USING (descriptor)
WHERE  p.lic_li_no IN (m.lic_li_no, m.orig_licli);
```

This picks one arbitrary row among matching rows in `mid_pts` for every qualifying row in table `point` - if it has any match at all after the `INNER JOIN`. (You may want `LEFT JOIN` to presesrve oints without match? Move filter expressions to the join clause in this case.)

Since you didn't disclose table definitions, I am falling back to `ctid` to uniquely identify rows. (Use the PK instead if there is one.)

For your very few matches per point (close to one), `DISTINCT ON` should perform very well. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

About `ctid`:

- [Is the system column "ctid" legitimate for identifying rows to delete?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214422/is-the-system-column-ctid-legitimate-for-identifying-rows-to-delete/214443#214443)