# PostgreSQL Index Only Scan can NOT return ctid

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-11, physical-design, postgresql-performance

I have this table in PostgreSQL 11:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id bigint PRIMARY KEY, text text)
```

Now I want to fetch the `ctid` of rows meeting some condition like `id = 123`.

However, even using `pg_hint_plan` to hint PostgreSQL to use *Index Only Scan*, it will always give me *Index Scan*:

```
/*+ IndexOnlyScan(a) */ explain analyze select ctid from a where id = 823977776533426178;
                                                QUERY PLAN                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using a_pkey on a  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = '823977776533426178'::bigint)
 Planning Time: 0.122 ms
 Execution Time: 0.095 ms
(4 rows)
```

My understanding is that `ctid` is the physical row id (block_no: record_offset) of each row and it must be included in any btree index, since it needs this information to fetch the row from heap file.

Then why can't an index-only scan return the `ctid` directly?
Is it just that PostgreSQL does not implement it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is almost but not quite correct. True, every btree index tuple needs a `ctid` (or some form of block number and tuple index) to point to the heap tuple (table row). But (at least) since the introduction of ["heap-only tuples"](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD) with Postgres 8.3, there may be a **HOT chain** to follow to arrive at the current live tuple in the snapshot - with a **different `ctid`** than the one stored in the index.

Since it is also not possible to use the `ctid` (or any system column) as index expression, it is currently (and for the forseeable future) ***completely impossible*** to get a `ctid` from an index-only scan.

Related:

- [Redundant data in update statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806610/939860)
- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers/66007#66007)

Quoting the [Postgres Wiki on Index-only_scans / Interaction_with_HOT](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Interaction_with_HOT):

> With HOT, it became possible for an index scan to traverse a so-called
>   HOT chain; it could get from the physical index tuple (which would
>   probably have been created by an original INSERT, and related to an
>   earlier version of the logical tuple), to the corresponding physical
>   heap tuple. The heap tuple would itself contain a pointer to the next
>   version of the tuple (that is, the tuple ctid), which might, in turn,
>   have a pointer of its own. The index scan eventually arrives at tuple
>   that is current according to the query's snapshot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise answer! It makes sense. But a the same time I wonder in terms of the possibility of implementing this, the query just return the head `ctid` of the **HOT chain** from index-only scan, and let the downstream operations to handle the fetching of real current version record from heap file. Because the `ctid` is an internal id anyway, this implementation does no harm and also solve my problem. Is this proposal possible? If yes, it might be a potential improvement of PostgreSQL?