# Deleting would-be orphans when creating FK in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, restore, foreign-key, constraint, referential-integrity

I am working on a script that replicates schema and data. I first create all the structure except for `foreign keys` after reading it from the source's `system tables`, then copy the data, then create the FKs so that if a would-be orphan gets inserted in a child table after I copied the parent (while I am running the script), I still get the basic schema and the data, even though the FK creation fails due to the orphan data.

My next step is to do something like wrap a `try/catch` around the create FK statement and, if it fails, delete the orphan data that caused it. Doing this will be somewhat complicated because I would have to extract all the reference keys and assemble my own delete statement (I currently don't do that because PG system tables provide a ready `REFERENCES` statement which I can concatenate).

But I am wondering if there is a way to do a `ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT fk_y FOREIGN KEY ... DELETE ANY WOULD-BE ORPHANS` which would save me that step.

So if my parent table is:

```
 parent_id     | parent_name
---------------------------------
 1             | Joe
 2             | Mary
```

and the child is:

```
child_id      | child_name     | parent_parent_id
--------------------------------------------------
 11           | Jimmy          | 1
 21           | Joey           | 2
 31           | Jeff           | 3
```

'Jeff' would be deleted before enforcing referential integrity because his parent and he were introduced in the source after the source parent was copied to the target. Then the FK can be created against consistent data.

---

Clarifications (from comments / chat discussion):

> Do you read the data in a single transaction or not?

- I don't use a single transaction as it would be too huge. I break the retrieved data by table and for some large tables by table segment (batch of 5000 or 10000 rows).
- This is essentially an ETL that makes an "evil twin" out of a DB. hope that makes sense.
- On average a DB copy in my environment takes between 20 min (for smalled DBs) to 1.5-2 hrs (for larger DBs) some tables have millions of rows. I load chunk by chunk in the memory of my Python script

> What about `pg_dump` or `pg_basebackup`?

- My app does some other things that `pg_dump` doesn't do, such as better logging. Also, pg_dump expects the same users on both the source and target and a host of other issues. I tried it, didn't like it. I like my tool much better, I want to  work through this minor issue that is left and happens only sporadically.

Comment: Discussion on this question has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50172/discussion-on-question-by-amphibient-deleting-would-be-orphans-when-creating-fk)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been suggested in comments, the standard tool [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) might serve you better. It takes a consistent snapshot and preserves referential integrity during backup automatically - given the source DB is consistent (FK constraints in place). Use it if you can!

<sub>The related tools [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) and [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) have also been mentioned, but those work on whole DB *clusters* while you obviously only want to copy (parts of) a single database.</sub>

**However**, there may still be valid reasons for the question. It seems unfair to turn it down on speculation. The question itself is interesting enough:

***How to import inconsistent data into a FK relationship and fix it?***

#### `NOT VALID` option

There is no `DELETE ANY WOULD-BE ORPHANS` option in the creation of FK constraints (like you'd wish), but the related ***`NOT VALID`*** option for `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in Postgres **9.1 or later** should be instrumental. [The manual on `ALTER TABLE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

> ```
> ADD table_constraint [ NOT VALID ]
> ```
>
> This form adds a new constraint to a table using the same syntax as
>   [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html), plus the option `NOT VALID`, which is currently only
>   allowed for foreign key and CHECK constraints. If the constraint is
>   marked `NOT VALID`, the potentially-lengthy initial check to verify that
>   all rows in the table satisfy the constraint is skipped. The
>   constraint will still be enforced against subsequent inserts or
>   updates (that is, they'll fail unless there is a matching row in the
>   referenced table, in the case of foreign keys; and they'll fail unless
>   the new row matches the specified check constraints). But the database
>   will not assume that the constraint holds for all rows in the table,
>   until it is validated by using the `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` option.

So you can create involved tables and import data and create PK constraints, and FK constraints with `NOT VALID`.

```
ALTER TABLE child ADD CONSTRAINT child_parent_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(parent_id) NOT VALID;
```

That prevents any new writes from violating referential integrity, while tolerating existing violations. (And the system is aware of it.)

Delete orphans later, at the earliest opportunity:

```
DELETE FROM child c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM parent p
   WHERE  p.parent_id = c.parent_id
   );
```

This does nothing if the data is consistent, and the work needs to be done either way to verify integrity. So it won't get any more efficient for unreliable data that needs verification.

*Then* validate the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE child VALIDATE CONSTRAINT child_parent_id_fkey;
```

Doesn't have to be in the same transaction. [Read the manual for details.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

Related:

- [Partial db dump/restore](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81097/partial-db-dump-restore/81188#81188)
- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/disable-all-constraints-and-table-checks-while-restoring-a-dump/75635#75635)

Comment: Regarding the *"while you obviously only want to copy (parts of) a single database."* I mentioned them (basebackup, dumpall) because the OP (in comments, not in the question) commented that they didn't like pg_dump because it doesn't save roles info. I suppose it should be an edit in the question, with the exact requirements ("need to save roles as well", can't use pg_basebackup`, read only access to the source, full access to the target, etc)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Yes, one of these tools may be useful after all. The question is a bit light on the objective. As so often the OP is focused on his projected solution, instead of presenting the underlying problem. The question itself seems interesting enough, though.

Answer (score -1):

> I am working on a script that replicates schema and data. I first create all the structure **except for foreign keys** after reading it from the source's system tables, **then copy the data, then create the FKs** so that if a would-be orphan gets inserted in a child table after I copied the parent (while I am running the script), I still get the basic schema and the data, even though the FK creation fails due to the orphan data.

This is not sound design. **Integrity first, always**. What you're describing leaves your database in a state that requires later clean-up.

What you really want is to set up a schema that is tight, and fool proof and then to  [`INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) This will skip rows that fail to make the foreign key constraint.

Shy of that, if you already have dirty data, and you just want to delete that you need to

1. `BEGIN` a transaction
2. `DELETE` the rows that conflict
3. add the foreign keys `CONSTRAINTS`
4. `COMMIT` the transaction.

There is nothing that does `DELETE ANY WOULD-BE ORPHANS`, and that would be a *bad* idea. The above is the closest you can get.

Comment: i do not have the control transaction in the source database.  I am not a DB.  I only have read access.  this does not answer it.

Comment: If you only read access, how do you intend to delete would be orphans? you can delete orphans, you can modify the schema to have foreign key constraints, but you can't insert data properly?

Comment: I have read access in the source, I do control the target. I can do everything on the target. what you're not understanding is that the script is designed to replicate any PG DB, much like `pg_dump` but it is more sophisticated.  the script does not know anything about the schema before it actually connects and reads the system tables.  but there is a latency between table creation (T0), data insertion (T1) and finally constraint enforcement (T3). since I am using the data just for testing, the doesn't have to be 100% like in the source but the schema does. at T3, I want to delete all obstacle

Comment: the data doesn't have to be 100% but the schema does.  that is why i don't mind deletion of would-be orphans, i can do it manually when the process fails and i see which table it failed on.  but i would like if i could enable the script to do it for me. i hope this makes sense

Comment: Databases don't work around your script. Create the tables with the schema and the foreign key constraints, or file a bug with the script creators. Shy of that, if the constraints are on the original table, then where are you getting the data with the orphans?