# How do I remove duplicate records in a table?

Tags: sql-server, duplication

I have a table table1 with  1 millions rows of data.

I want to remove all the duplicate records in the table1

I was looking at this link:

> [How do I remove duplicate records in a join table in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36539/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-records-in-a-join-table-in-postgresql)

Can you tell me how to do this below query in SQL server?

```
 DELETE FROM questions_tags q
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   questions_tags q1
   WHERE  q1.ctid < q.ctid
   AND    q.question_id = q1.question_id
   AND    q.tag_id = q1.tag_id
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is just slightly different:

```
DELETE q
FROM dbo.questions_tags AS q
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM   dbo.questions_tags AS q1
   WHERE  q1.ctid < q.ctid
   AND    q.question_id = q1.question_id
   AND    q.tag_id = q1.tag_id
);
```

Personally, I prefer to use a CTE. Then I can easily swap in a `SELECT` to validate what I am about to delete, and easily change the where clause to validate what I am going to keep:

```
;WITH q AS 
(
  SELECT question_id, tag_id, ctid,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY question_id, tag_id ORDER BY ctid)
  FROM dbo.question_tags
)
--DELETE q
SELECT * FROM q 
WHERE rn > 1; -- to show keepers, change to = 1
```

> I *believe* these semantics match yours, but please test.

Then, of course, add a proper key constraint before you let anybody insert any new nonsense into this table.

Comment: I had to replace `ctid` by `%%physloc%%` because SQL Server 2016 wasn't recognizing `ctid`.