# There is a column named in table but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql, subquery, duplication

I've been learning Postgres (coming from SQL Server), and this error really confuses me.

Here is the code with some sample data:

```
create table T (
ID serial primary key,
A varchar(1),
B varchar(1),
C varchar(1)
)
```

↑ Testing table.

```
insert into T (A, B, C)
values('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

↑ Insert duplicates

```
delete from T
where ID in (
    select t.ID
    from (  select ID, row_number() over (partition by A,B,C order by A,B,C) as rn
            from T) as t
    where t.rn < (select max(t.rn) from t)
    )
```

↑ Delete duplicate keeping the last entry.

The problem is in the `(select max(t.rn) from t)` I am assuming this is a noob mistake related to not knowing postgres syntax when it comes to referencing columns with aliases?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you can simplify this by using `dense_rank() over (... order by a desc, b desc, c desc) as rn` and then use `where t.rn > 1` removing the need for the `max()` subquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, `partition by A,B,C order by A,B,C` makes no sense. Since you intent to keep the "last" row (meaning the one with the greatest `ID`), you probably meant:

```
partition by A,B,C order by ID
```

**Still**, the syntax is invalid on top of this. This subquery expression contains a reference to a column of the outer query: `(select max(t.rn) from t)`. The scope of the subquery does not include columns from the outer query so `rn` is not visible in there. Only columns of the table `t` are.

You could use a CTE to allow the reference and make the syntax *valid*:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION by a,b,c ORDER BY id) AS rn FROM t)
DELETE FROM t
WHERE  id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM   cte
    WHERE  rn < (SELECT max(rn) FROM cte)
    )
```

**Still**, the query is dangerous nonsense. **Do not use this!**
Comparing to the *greatest* row number is logical nonsense as each group of peers might have a different number of dupes. Would delete a lot more than it should.

Simpler, and correct:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE  id IN (
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION by a,b,c ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn FROM t) t1
    WHERE  t1.rn > 1  --  all but the latest
    );
```

Which, in turn, can be had more cheaply as (assuming all columns `NOT NULL`!):

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM t AS t1
   WHERE t1.a = t.a
   AND   t1.b = t.b
   AND   t1.c = t.c
   AND   t1.id > t.id
   );
```

*"... where a dupe exists with a greater ID"*.

Related:

- [How do I remove duplicate records in a join table in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36539/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-records-in-a-join-table-in-postgresql/36614#36614)

Comment: I already changed it actually, noticed it as well but forgot to update the OP. But I am still interested in why I am getting that error.

Comment: @Chessbrain: I added an explanation for the error.

Comment: Though I'm not sure of core issue, select max(column) + 1 worked for me