# Find rows in a single table where values in a certain column are near-duplicates

Tags: postgresql, query, amazon-rds, duplication, like

I have a Postgres 11 table on RDS containing a column `email`; some of the values in this column [and only that column] are clearly de facto duplicates but differ in case, i.e., different capitalization, such as:

```
foo@****.com
Foo@****.com
```

To be clear, none of the present rows are true duplicates, nor share precisely the same values in that column. My objective is to identify these records [and, once found, eliminate/merge the de-facto duplicates].

My initial inclination was to use a self-join, e.g.:

```
SELECT c.email 
FROM schema.table c 
INNER JOIN schema.table d ON lower(c.email) = lower(d.email)
ORDER BY c.email;
```

However, this returns *all* the email records rather than only those that are de-facto-duplications.

Using a subquery such as the following produces a similar [i.e., too-inclusive] result:

```
SELECT c.email, alias.email 
FROM schema.table c 
  JOIN (SELECT email FROM schema.table) alias ON lower(c.email) = lower(alias.email);
```

Since I’m not looking for an aggregate, but rather a case-insensitive comparison, it seems to me that a window function is not the correct approach.

I think that this should be a straightforward query, but I’m having a difficult time seeing it clearly and am sure there is an error in the way I’m conceiving of the problem; it’s pretty frustrating.

In addition to searching here and on SO, I consulted Molinaro’s *SQL Cookbook*, but to no avail.

What is the correct way to structure the query so that it returns only those records whose `email` values are the same, disregarding case?

edit note : my initial question formulation expressed a misguided inclination to use ILIKE for case-insensitive matching, but the use of lower() as suggested in the below answers is far more sensible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another case for [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
SELECT *
FROM   schema.table t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM schema.table t1
   WHERE  lower(t.email) = lower(t1.email)
   AND    t.ctid <> t1.ctid
   )
ORDER   BY lower(email), email;
```

If you have a PK, use it instead of `ctid`. Related:

- [How do I remove duplicate records in a join table in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36539/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-records-in-a-join-table-in-postgresql/36614#36614)

This returns every qualifying row ***once***. The added `ORDER BY` helps to keep dupes together and in deterministic sort order (unless your locale is case insensitive).

Why not use a simple join?

If you have, say, 10 variants of the same email, a simple join would give you *10 over 2* = 90 rows, and repeat every combination with reversed roles. Basically a limited [Carthesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all dupes for each set of dupes.

Related:

- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337500/939860)

A trigram index as suggested there should greatly help performance with tables of non-trivial size.

Also note that `lower(t.email) = lower(t1.email)` is slightly different from `t.email ILIKE t1.email`. The latter treats the right side as *pattern*, where some characters have special meaning unless you escape them. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630/939860)

Comment: Fantastic and crystal clear explanation -- worked an absolute treat -- thanks also for the tip re : trigram index -- will upvote when I have sufficient rep to do so

Comment: I had to add "and t.email<> t1.email" to WHERE condition, so that I can see the same in lowercase but different in original.

Comment: @TomoMiha: `WHERE t.ctid <> t1.ctid` takes care of this while *"none of the present rows [...] share precisely the same values in that column."*

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the rows from each other:

```
SELECT c.email
  FROM schema.table c,
       schema.table d
 WHERE lower(c.email) = lower(d.email)
   AND c.email <> d.email;
```

One question you will need to answer (and I will update my answer if relevant) -- are you using `ILIKE` because you want partial matches too?  Like, are `bert@foo.com` and `RObert@foo.com` supposed to be considered duplicates?  (I would assume not, but when people use `ILIKE`, it's usually to patch parts of strings, as in the bert/robert example)

Comment: You probably want `and c.primary_key_column <> d.primary_key_column`

Comment: Brilliant! You're absolutely right, I had no reason to use ILIKE when I could have simply used lower().  Editing my question to reflect this.  Thanks a whole bunch richyen and @a_horse_with_no_name  -- will upvote when I have sufficient reputation to do so.

Comment: This starts multiplying rows if there can be more than two variants of the same email - and even returns each combination twice for just two - unless you use something like `and c.primary_key_column > d.primary_key_column` (instead of `<>`).  I added an answer explaining why.